# Is there a field of mathematics that deals with the strange properties of numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, terminology, recreational-mathematics

This blog thread lists lots of strange number properties...
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-beautiful-number-and-why

Is there a field of mathematics that deals with these strange number properties? I thought maybe this was "number theory" but a quick look at the definition of that subject makes me think it is not the right name.

A fair amount of mysticism seems mixed into the blog comments, but despite that there are lots of weird ratios and patterns described.

Comment: Number theory deals primarily with whole numbers.  So a number theorist will be interested in why the number 1729 is unusual.  Not sure there's a specific other field that deals with strange numbers in general.  But maybe a book like "Numbers: Rational and Irrational" by Niven would be interesting to you.  Find it here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0055AKUKK

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology

Comment: Visit oeis.org , the online encyclopedia of integer sequences.  If a number has an unusual property, then other numbers might also have that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of mathematics that deals with the properties of the naturals numbers (which it seems you are asking about) is in fact called number theory. Lots of peculiar number properties that are not directly related to the natural numbers can often be explained quite well using number theoretic understanding. Whether or not these properties are deemed "strange" does not affect what field they are in. It is *how* they are studied that defines what "field" their properties are in.

I would highly recommended checking out the YouTube channel [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/@numberphile) is you are especially intrigued by unique numbers and unique number categories.

Comment: Thanks for looking at a old, old question! I'll be checking out that YouTube channel.

Comment: Happy to help, and Numberphile has some awesome stuff. Hope you'll like it!